# C# populated DropDownList: Values are not displayed on debugger

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I am trying to see the inserted values of the DDL control though I can only see info about the control (like location, colour, etc.)! How can I see the actual data it carries?

Ofcourse I am looking at an established project and the data are there, the question is HOW I can show them to the debugger, in the Watch pane for example.

Thanks,

Sun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inspecting the **Items** property and iterate through the items using indexes.

Example: ddlSomthing.Items[0]

You can also use the **Watch** window to inspect the properties in details.

Hope that helps.

Comment: C# has way more properties/events than it could have had!!! ;) A little bit tedious to get around some things I think... Anyway, thanks for the info...